# Chrome Greasemonkey script suddenly not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, gmail, greasemonkey, userscripts

Years ago I wrote a Greasemonkey userscript specifically for Chrome that disabled the "sponsored link" advertising in Gmail, as well as a couple of other tweaks. The script itself is super simple, and doesn't rely on any third party libraries, etc: http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/52619

As of a few days ago (possibly when I upgraded to Chrome 11), the script no longer works. I've checked out Gmail's source code (which is known to change frequently), but all the hooks I use are still in place.

It seems like Chrome 11 just no longer runs my script at all - does anybody know about any changes in Chrome that may have caused that?

/EDIT I should note that the CSS I insert still works - so the script is at least being recognized.

Comment: if part of the script is executing and another part is not, then something is wrong with the code in the script. Probably a Gmail change that you haven't figured out yet.

Answer (score 0):

I use ChromeStylist (similar to Stylish) to run CSS on webpages. I do this in combination with MVPS hosts file, and I disable the Web Clips in the mail settings. I see no ads at all in my GMail. Here's the CSS I use, perhaps it may be of some use:

```
.u5,.u7,.nH.OH0apf{display:none!important}
```

Comment: I like the webclips bar for RSS. As I said my script worked fine until a few days ago ;)